# can you bold text in a jquery confirm dialog box?

Tags: jquery, html

I have the following jquery code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function() {
        $(".deleteuser").click(function(){ return confirm("Are you sure you want to delete this user?")});
        });
</script>
```

I'd like to be able to bold the text inside the confirm dialog box ... so something like:
(pseudocode)

```
$(".deleteuser").click(function(){ return confirm("Are you sure you want to delete this user? <b>Note:</b> It can't be undone!")});
```

Thank you!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can't do this with standard javascript popups.

You'll need to use a custom library such as one of the below:

- [jQueryUI](http://jqueryui.com/)
- [MooTools](http://mootools.net/)
- [Prototype](http://www.prototype-ui.com/)
- [Scriptaculous](http://script.aculo.us/)
- [Yahoo User Interface](http://developer.yahoo.com/yui/)

Comment: Warrent, i'm already using jquery so maybe i will explore jquery ui.  can you tell me what I should google to find some examples?

Comment: Look into jQuery Dialog boxes with confirmation - http://jqueryui.com/dialog/#modal-confirmation

Comment: Note that their download builder: http://jqueryui.com/download/ allows you to select the components you require - so if you don't want the whole UI library, you are able to select the minimum requirements + Dialog.

Answer (score 0):

Try this example from http://jqueryui.com/dialog/:

```
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8" />
<title>jQuery UI Dialog - Basic modal</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.3/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css" />
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.3/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<script>

$(function() {
    $( "#dialog-confirm" ).dialog({
        resizable: false,
        autoOpen: false,
        modal: true,
        buttons: {
            "Delete all items": function() {
                $( this ).dialog( "close" );
            },
            Cancel: function() {
                $( this ).dialog( "close" );
            }
        }
    });
    $( "#opener" ).click(function() {
        $( "#dialog-confirm" ).dialog( "open" );
    });
});


</script>
</head>
<body>
<div id="dialog-confirm" title="Empty the recycle bin?">
<p><span class="ui-icon ui-icon-alert" style="float: left; margin: 0 7px 20px 0;"></span>These items will be permanently deleted and cannot be recovered. Are you sure?</p>
</div>
<button id="opener">Delete user</button>

</body>
</html>
```